# Mobile screen/viewport size detection - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to report the screen size of a mobile device and update on orientation change but am getting all sorts of strange errors e.g. width almost always 980px.

This works fine on desktop when resizing but not mobile (reporting landscape or portrait is fine though)

Tried on ipad, samsung galaxy tab, google nexus phone and iphone 4

Here's what I'm using:

```
// get dimensions
_getScreenWidth = function() {
  var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var el = document.getElementById('dimensions');
  _handleOrientation();
  el.innerHTML = 'Width: '+screenWidth +' :: Height: '+screenHeight + "<br /><br />" + _doc_element.className;
};

// portait or landscape
_handleOrientation = function() {
 if (device.landscape()) {
  _removeClass("portrait");
  return _addClass("landscape");
 } else {
  _removeClass("landscape");
  return _addClass("portrait");
 }
};

// resize event
var resizeTimeout;
window.onresize = function() {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
  // handle normal resize
  resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    _getScreenWidth();
  }, 250); // 250ms delay
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not get width in physical pixels. Instead, you'll receive "CSS pixels". This is why you getting strange errors. For orientation detecting, you can use "CSS pixels", just compare width to height.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `device.landscape()` is supposed to be, but the `device` object doesn't exist, at least not in standard browsers.

> all sorts of strange errors

In my case, that was due to undefined `_addClass` and `_removeClass` functions, `_doc_element` object and as mentioned above, `device.landscape()`.

To fix `device.landscape()`, you can define landscape as a mode where width > height. Then it's just a simple comparison:

```
isLandscape = function() {
  return window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight;
}
```

Here is [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maremp/msr7fuja/) with all of the errors fixed. Tested on iPhone 6 and it's setting correct classes.